# Stop query from checking further with "between dates" condition after all dates are found in sorted table

Tags: sql, sql-server, bigdata

I have a very large table with a column that contains dates. Due to the table being so huge, I want to request the data for e.g. each day, which I am trying to do with the following statement:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [my_db].[dbo].[my_data] where date between '2019-03-25' and '2019-03-26'
```

So far so good, when I run this query, the relevant data (about 10,000 rows) are returned. However, the query does not stop, it keeps executing for a very long time (couldn't see how long, I always stopped it after about 30 minutes).
I assume it's checking for more fitting dates. However, the table is sorted, so *I* know there won't be any further dates.

What is the best approach to handle this here? Is there a way to set some kind of timeout after no futher result was found? Or should I just use a normal timeout and hope the transaction was done in time? Thanks!

Comment: `the table is sorted,` there's no such thing. There's no implied order in a table. No result order is guaranteed unless an ORDER BY clause is used. Not that it would matter. Query performance is affected by indexes, not the physical sort order. How large is the table? Is `date` indexed? If not, the server will have to scan the entire table because there's **no** guarantee that there won't be a matching row at the very end

Comment: In any case, when laptops can easily run databases with multi-GB tables, `large` means billions of rows. For the query to take 30 minutes, either `date` isn't indexed or this isn't the real query, and other conditions force a full table scan. 10K rows is *no* data

Comment: Post the actual query, actual table schema, size, and the query's execution plan. BTW `between '2019-03-25' and '2019-03-26'` will return data for two days, assuming `date` is actually a `date`-typed field

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't know how large the table is, since a `select count(*) from table` also doesn't complete on my laptop. I'm connected via a VPN, that might be a bottleneck. I assume the table has a few dozen million rows, maybe in the low hundreds.
I couldn't find a way to quickly find whether the `date` column was indexed, but I'd assume it's not.
I understand that there is no sorted table, but SSMS does find the data at the very "beginning" first and displays it and then never finishes, that's what I meant.
The query is what you see here, nothing more. I'm just starting out.

Comment: That's still not big data. The important question remains - is the column indexed? And if you connect through VPN, how much data is transferred over the wire? How long does `SELECT count(*)
  FROM [my_db].[dbo].[my_data] where date between '2019-03-25' and '2019-03-26'` take? If it's fast, the problem is the VPN. If the column isn't indexed, there's no way to improve performance. Tables are *not* sorted. If, and only if, they have a clustered index on a field, you can assume that the data pages follow that field's order. The queries are accelerated by that index though, not the order

Comment: The `count` takes "forever", as far as I'm concerned. I'm running it right now and it's already at two minutes. I haven't seen it complete. However, another table with about 3.8 million rows also took a long time to complete, I don't remember how long exactly, probably around five minutes.

Would you say indexing the date column might fix this?

Comment: That means the field isn't indexed. It has to be indexed. There's no other way to accelerate queries. There's no "might", without indexes the server has no idea what's in that field, so it *has* to check all values.

Comment: *After* indexing, there are various techniques you can use to further improve performance. Compressing the table reduces the disk IO, thus improving performance. The main delays in a database server is reading from disk, not CPU, so compression offers a clear benefit. It's transparent too, which means you don't have to modify queries and applications

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I will suggest indexing the column.

Comment: Another way to get the total number of rows in a table is opening the Properties window of the table in SQL Management Studio and look in page Storage. Property Row count shows the total number of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like your query is performing a `table scan` to retrieve your data.

We don't know anything about the performance of your hardware but for a large table, possibly highly fragmented, this could be a time consuming operation on a slow drive or if IO is a bottleneck.

You can quickly get the approximate count of rows in several ways. Reading the comments you mention you are doing this on a laptop, so likely you are the only user in which case the approximate count is likely bang-on.

The easiest is to run

```
exec sp_spaceused 'tablename'
```

You can query a list of indexes on a table

```
select * from sys.indexes where object_id=Object_Id('tablename')
```

You can also see a list of all tables and their stats including rows using *Object Explorer Details* in SSMS. Connect to your server and expand the database from the list in Object Explorer. Open the *Details* panel (F7) and click on *Tables*, the list will be populated and rowcounts retrieved.

You can also expand `Tables` in Object Explorer, expand your specific table and then expand `Indexes` to view what is currently defined.

Because you (probably) have no index on your `Date` column, even though *you* know you have received all the qualifying results, SQL Server *doesn't* because it is having to *scan* the table. without an index, nothing guarantees a range of rows will all reside sequentially.

This means it jumps right in at one end and starts reading through page-by-page until it gets to the end, checking each row to see if it fits your filtering criteria. If the data you are expecting happens to reside on the first pages it reads then great - but SQL Server has no way of knowing it's found every possible qualifying row - many factors such as page fragmentation could mean some rows might exist further along the list of pages making up the table's data.

An index on the `date` column would help dramatically because then SQL server can *seek* directly to the start of the first qualifying date and read the values *in order* until it has reached the last qualifying row, where because the data is *sorted* it knows it has reach the end.

An index will also help with a query such as `select count(*)`. Every index (except filtered indexes) includes every row, but not every column - therefore to get a row count SQL Server will scan the *narrowest* index, which means it will have the least possible IO.

In addition, doing `select *` if you don't actuall *need* every column will be an impact on performance.

If your query is highly selective, and you have an index on `date`, SQL Server will seek to the required rows in the index and then do a *bookmark lookup* to retrieve the remaining columns.

This is an expensive operation however, so there is a threshold where the trade-off is not worth it and SQL Server will opt to *scan* the table instead to avoid the lookup operation.